# Synchronization Problem - Try to log navigation and store the log by AsyncStorage

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, asyncstorage

I am tring to log the navigation between screens by useEffect with using the useIsFocusd. I have customized that the logs store locally by AsyncStorage, but I found some logs have disappeared. I think it should be a synchronization problem, but async/await is not available in useEffect.

Any suggestions to my case?

```
let log=await AsyncStorage.getItem('log')
log=JSON.parse(log)
/Such as, ABC Screen navigated
log.push(props.msg+'\n')
/*I think the problem happens when there are multiple logs write at the same time. For example, 1 read 2 read, and 2 write 1 write. In this case, log 2 cannot be saved, but I dont know how to tackle it*/
await AsyncStorage.setItem('log',JSON.stringify(log));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don‘t think that is the correct way to log the screen, you would have to implement logging for ich screen you wanna log.

In case you are using react navigation you can grab the screen in the NavigationContainer.

```js
import {
  NavigationContainer,
  useNavigationContainerRef,
} from '@react-navigation/native';

export default () => {
  const navigationRef = useNavigationContainerRef();
  const routeNameRef = useRef();

  return (
    <NavigationContainer
      ref={navigationRef}
      onReady={() => {
        routeNameRef.current = navigationRef.getCurrentRoute().name;
      }}
      onStateChange={async () => {
        const previousRouteName = routeNameRef.current;
        const currentRouteName = navigationRef.getCurrentRoute().name;
        const trackScreenView = () => {
          // Your implementation of analytics goes here!
        };

        if (previousRouteName !== currentRouteName) {
          // Save the current route name for later comparison
          routeNameRef.current = currentRouteName;
          
          // Replace the line below to add the tracker from a mobile analytics SDK
          await trackScreenView(currentRouteName);
        }
      }}
    >
      {/* ... */}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

[Explanation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-tracking/)

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I removed most of the logging call in isFocus useEffect and the problem is alleviated.

Comment: What does alleviated mean in this context?